# merge and sample two pandas time series

Tags: python, pandas

I have two time series. I would like to merge them and `asfreq(*, method='pad')` the result, restricted to the time range they share in common.

To illustrate, suppose I define `A` and `B` like this:

```
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

A = pd.Series(np.arange(4), index=pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2017,1,4,10,0,0), 
              periods=4, freq=dt.timedelta(seconds=10)))

B = pd.Series(np.arange(6), index=pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2017,1,4,10,0,7),
              periods=6, freq=dt.timedelta(seconds=3)))
```

So they look like:

```
# A
2017-01-04 10:00:00    0
2017-01-04 10:00:10    1
2017-01-04 10:00:20    2
2017-01-04 10:00:30    3

# B
2017-01-04 10:00:07    0
2017-01-04 10:00:10    1
2017-01-04 10:00:13    2
2017-01-04 10:00:16    3
2017-01-04 10:00:19    4
2017-01-04 10:00:22    5
```

I would like to compute something like:

```
# combine_and_asfreq(A, B, dt.timedelta(seconds=5))
# timestamp            A   B
2017-01-04 10:00:07    0   0
2017-01-04 10:00:12    1   1
2017-01-04 10:00:17    1   3
2017-01-04 10:00:22    2   5
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You could look at the function merge_asof. I think that's what that is supposed to do.  If that doesn't work you could do an outer join, resample, and then drop the remaining nan values. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof

Comment: How did you get the times in your final dataframe. Why are they spaced apart by 5 seconds?

Comment: @TedPetrou Just edited post to include a function call with a `timedelta(seconds=5)` argument passed in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you are asking but here is a somewhat convoluted method that first finds the overlapping time and creates a single column dataframe as the 'base' dataframe with the 5s timedelta.

## get started by setting up dataframes properly

```
start = max(A.index.min(), B.index.min())
end = min(A.index.max(), B.index.max())

df_time = pd.DataFrame({'time': pd.date_range(start,end,freq='5s')})

df_A = A.reset_index()
df_B = B.reset_index()

df_A.columns = ['time', 'value']
df_B.columns = ['time', 'value']
```

Now we have the following three dataframes.

**df_A**

```
                 time  value
0 2017-01-04 10:00:00      0
1 2017-01-04 10:00:10      1
2 2017-01-04 10:00:20      2
3 2017-01-04 10:00:30      3
```

**df_B**

```
                time  value
0 2017-01-04 10:00:07      0
1 2017-01-04 10:00:10      1
2 2017-01-04 10:00:13      2
3 2017-01-04 10:00:16      3
4 2017-01-04 10:00:19      4
5 2017-01-04 10:00:22      5
```

**df_time**

```
                 time
0 2017-01-04 10:00:07
1 2017-01-04 10:00:12
2 2017-01-04 10:00:17
3 2017-01-04 10:00:22
```

#### Use merge_asof to join all three

```
pd.merge_asof(pd.merge_asof(df_time, df_A, on='time'), df_B, on='time', suffixes=('_A', '_B'))


                 time  value_A  value_B
0 2017-01-04 10:00:07        0        0
1 2017-01-04 10:00:12        1        1
2 2017-01-04 10:00:17        1        3
3 2017-01-04 10:00:22        2        5
```